# is there is a way to update/ add a new widget CloudWatch dashboard using CloudFormation template?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I​ am trying to add lambda function stats to my dashboard using cloudformation but the problem is that the lambda function is created in a different stack than my dashboard which is created after the stack that has the dashboard. so is there is a way to update the dashboard after it was created using cloudformation

Answer (score 0):

Could you try updating the other cloudformation stack just in case right after and see if it helps. Btw you want to try creating cloudformation templates, there's an online tool available called [cloudkast](https://krunal4amity.github.io). It is an online aws cloudformation template generator.

Answer (score 0):

In CloudFormation, when referencing a resource in another stack, you use the intrinsic function:

`Fn::ImportValue` in your Dashboard CloudFormation.  See the [documentation](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html).

A good example of this can be found on the AWS blog - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-reference-resource/

```
{
   "Parameters":{
        "NetworkStackNameParameter":{
              "Type":"String"
      }
    },
"Resources" : {
  "WebServerInstance" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "Properties" : {
       "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
      "ImageId" : "ami-a1b23456",
      "NetworkInterfaces" : [{
        "GroupSet" : [{"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : 
"${NetworkStackNameParameter}-SecurityGroupID"}}],
        "AssociatePublicIpAddress" : "true",
        "DeviceIndex" : "0",
        "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
        "SubnetId" : {"Fn::ImportValue" : {"Fn::Sub" : "${NetworkStackNameParameter}- SubnetID"}}
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

The `SubnetId` above is pulled in  from another stack using the ImportValue.

The same can be done for the Lambda when building a dashboard using CloudFormation.